# Plotting eigenfunctions as functions of parameters in the hamiltonian

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, manipulate, dynamic, slider

I'm finding eigenfunctions using NDEigensystem of various hamiltonians. For example, the hamiltonian with Shcrödinger's equation:
$$ H u(x)=-\hbar^2 u''(x) + A x^2 u(x). $$
I would like to be able to vary parameters in the Hamiltonian using sliders and see the corresponding changes in the plots of the eigenfunctions. I'm quite new to Mathematica and have so far tried this:

```
  schrod[x_, \[HBar]_, A_] := -\[HBar]^2*u''[x] + A*x^2*u[x];

{vals, funs} = 
  NDEigensystem [schrod, u[x], {x, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, 8];
fun2 = funs[[2]];
Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate[Abs[fun2^2]], {x, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, 
  PlotRange -> Automatic], {x, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, {\[HBar], 0, 
  1}, {A, 0, 10}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There a couple of typos in your expression. You define `schrod` as a function but then you call it without arguments. There is no need to vary $\hbar$ and $A$ independently since you can rescale one into the other by changing the unit of time. Also $x$ is not variable of the `Manipulate` since it is used by the `Plot`.

Something like this would work

```
schrod[x_, A_] := -u''[x] + A*x^2*u[x];

Clear[vals, funs];
fun2[A_] := NDEigensystem[schrod[x,  A], u[x], {x, -2π, 2π}, 2][[2,2]];

Manipulate[ Plot[Evaluate[Abs[fun2[A]^2]], {x, -2 π, 2π}], {A, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

You can make it a bit more fun while varying the eigenfunction as well:

```
fun[A_, n_] := NDEigensystem[schrod[x, 1, A], u[x], {x,-2π,2 π}, n][[2, n]];

Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate[Abs[fun[A, n]^2]], {x, -2π, 2 π}], {A, 0, 10}
 , {n, 2, 4, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: It might be helpful to the OP, seeing as they are new, if you noted what differs, syntactically, between your example and their’s. I can comment this to them if you’d find that may be a better route to take!